# How can I change the state of a menu with a button inside tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to make a unit converter in tkinter. I made two drop-down menus; the first one allows the user to select the unit they want to convert from, and the second one allows them to choose the unit they want to convert to. I want to disable all the options that do not make sense in the second menu after they have selected an option in the first one (if they want to convert kilograms it would not make sense to choose centimeters in the second menu)

I have tried to use a StringVar() to change the state of the menu, but it is not working. I have no idea of what to do next. I have been using the documentation of Tutorialspoint, but I cannot find anything that works (first time using tkinter).

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('600x600')

my_var = tk.StringVar()
my_var.set('active')

unit_1 = tk.Menubutton(root,text='This is the first menu button',bg='white',activebackground='#2E64FE',activeforeground='#FFFFFF')

menu_1 = tk.Menu(unit_1)
unit_1.config(menu=menu_1)

menu_1.add_command(label='Inches',command= lambda: my_var.set('disabled') )

menu_1.add_command(label='Kilograms')

unit_2 = tk.Menubutton(root,text='This is the second menu button',bg='white',activebackground='#2E64FE',activeforeground='#FFFFFF')

menu_2 = tk.Menu(unit_2)
unit_2.config(menu=menu_2)

menu_2.add_command(label='Centimeters')

menu_2.add_command(label='Pounds',state= my_var.get())

unit_1.place(relx=0.03,rely=0.08,relheight=0.04,relwidth=0.45)
unit_2.place(relx=0.52,rely=0.08,relheight=0.04,relwidth=0.45)

root.mainloop()
```

Here I am trying to make the button 'Inches' in the first menu to disable the button 'Pounds' in the second menu, but when I click on 'Inches' nothing happens to 'Pounds'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tk.StringVar()` is used to change text on something, for example if you want to have a button with dynamic text, you may want to use a `tk.StringVar()` for that.

What you want to do is something different; you want to change the configuration of a label. So you need to find the element and adjust its state:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('600x600')

my_var = tk.StringVar()
my_var.set('active')

unit_1 = tk.Menubutton(root,text='This is the first menu button',bg='white',activebackground='#2E64FE',activeforeground='#FFFFFF')

menu_1 = tk.Menu(unit_1)
unit_1.config(menu=menu_1)

menu_1.add_command(label='Inches', command=lambda: disable_pounds())

menu_1.add_command(label='Kilograms', command=lambda: disable_centimeters())

unit_2 = tk.Menubutton(root,text='This is the second menu button',bg='white',activebackground='#2E64FE',activeforeground='#FFFFFF')

menu_2 = tk.Menu(unit_2)
unit_2.config(menu=menu_2)

menu_2.add_command(label='Centimeters')

menu_2.add_command(label='Pounds',state= my_var.get())

unit_1.place(relx=0.03,rely=0.08,relheight=0.04,relwidth=0.45)
unit_2.place(relx=0.52,rely=0.08,relheight=0.04,relwidth=0.45)


def disable_pounds():
    menu_2.entryconfig("Pounds", state="disabled")
    menu_2.entryconfig("Centimeters", state="active")


def disable_centimeters():
    menu_2.entryconfig("Pounds", state="active")
    menu_2.entryconfig("Centimeters", state="disabled")



root.mainloop()
```